# Parent object is null in one-to-many relationship extending IdentityUser

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to extend ASP.NET IdentityUser to include a reference to a Customer.

I extend the `IdentityUser` class as:

```
[Index(nameof(Id), IsUnique = true)]
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public MyCustomer? Customer { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

And the `MyCustomer` class is:

```
[Index(nameof(Id), IsUnique = true)]
public class MyCustomer
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Customer")]
    public ICollection<MyUser> Users { get; } = new List<MyUser>();
}
```

And the `IdentityDbContext` class is:

```
public class MyIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser>
{
    public DbSet<MyCustomer> AspNetCustomers { get; set; }

    public MyIdentityDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyIdentityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

I am able to add the user to the customer, and see the appropriate foreign key in the `AspNetUsers` table:

[image: AspNetUsers]

But when I retrieve the users from the `UserManager` ...

```
var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("userName");
```

... the returned `MyUser` has a `CustomerId` value, but the `Customer` is null:

[image: NullCustomer]

However, when I retrieve customer from the DbContext ...

```
var customer = _context.AspNetCustomers.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
```

... the nested user in the `List<MyUser>` has both `CustomerId` and `Customer` populated.

My goal here is to have the `Customer` available in the user that is returned by `UserManager` without having to pull the entire customer catalog.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `UserManager` may not automatically include related entities when retrieving `users`. You can use the `Include` method to eagerly load the Customer when querying for a user.

```
var user = await userManager.Users
    .Include(u => u.Customer)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == "userName");
```

Alternatively, you can update the `MyUser` class to use the virtual keyword for the navigation property:

```
[Index(nameof(Id), IsUnique = true)]
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public virtual MyCustomer? Customer { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

By making the `Customer` property `virtual`, Entity Framework can enable lazy loading for this property. With lazy loading, the related `Customer` will be automatically loaded when accessed.

Comment: I was able to get the Customer by using the eager `Include`, but the lazy loading method still gives a null Customer object.